# Long Array Formula to be split in smaller parts (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long array formula which I am trying to break in smaller parts in order to apply it through VBA, here is the working formula (in Excel):

```
=IF(C7="MOR",IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*("MOR"=$C$7:$C$43),0)),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*("AFT"=$C$7:$C$43),0))),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*("EVE"=$C$7:$C$43),0))),IF(C7="AFT",IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*("AFT"=$C$7:$C$43),0)),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*("EVE"=$C$7:$C$43),0))),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*("MOR"=$C$7:$C$43),0))),IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*("EVE"=$C$7:$C$43),0)),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*("AFT"=$C$7:$C$43),0))),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*("MOR"=$C$7:$C$43),0)))))
```

This is the code in VBA:

```vb
Dim part1, part2, part3 As String
Dim part1, part2, part3 As String

part1 = "=IF(C7=""MOR"",IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(""MOR""=$C$7:$C$43),0)),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(""AFT""=$C$7:$C$43),0))),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(""EVE""=$C$7:$C$43),0))) ,(""XXX2""))  "
part2 = ",IF(C7=""AFT"",IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(""AFT""=$C$7:$C$43),0)),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(""EVE""=$C$7:$C$43),0))),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(""MOR""=$C$7:$C$43),0))) ,(""XXX3"")  "
part3 = ",IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(""EVE""=$C$7:$C$43),0)),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(""AFT""=$C$7:$C$43),0))),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(""MOR""=$C$7:$C$43),0))))) "


With ActiveSheet.Range("W7")
.FormulaArray = part1
.Replace "XXX2", part2
.Replace "XXX3", part3
End With
```

I am getting the error

> run-time error '1004': Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class

here:

```vb
.FormulaArray = part1
```

What I can't understand is that if I copy paste the VBA code from the immediate window in Excel, the formula doesn't give me any error.

I have also counted the characters, with spaces there are 246.

So I wonder, other than how to solve this problem, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Rearrange the formula so it is less than 255 characters: `=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(C7=$C$7:$C$43),0)),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(IF(C7<>"AFT","AFT","EVE")=$C$7:$C$43),0))),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(IF(C7<>"MOR","MOR","EVE")=$C$7:$C$43),0)))`

Comment: Interestingly, it works with `Formula` (but not `FormulaArray`), which is strange because `part1` appears to be a valid formula that is shorter than 255 characters. But even though it succeeds in setting the `part1` with `Formula`, it does not replace XXX2 and XXX3 (which happens when the resulting formula is invalid; the formula has to be valid and self-sufficient at all stages of replacement).

Comment: @GSerg my formula is less than 255 character and does not need any replacements. And will do what the other formula is doing.

Comment: @GSerg I am proposing an alternative formula that is shorter and does what the other longer formula does and as such no longer needs the replacement to make work.  just the simple: `ActiveSheet.Range("W7").FormulaArray = =IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(C7=$C$7:$C$43),0)),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(IF(C7<>"AFT","AFT","EVE")=$C$7:$C$43),0))),INDEX($K$7:$K$43,MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(IF(C7<>"MOR","MOR","EVE")=$C$7:$C$43),0)))` is all that is needed.

Comment: @ScottCraner That is fine, but I am still curious why `part1` would not work when it seems like it should.

Comment: @GSerg my guess is the `""` issue.

Comment: @ScottCraner You are very smart, I tested your formula and it seems it's working fine. I have only very few doubts about some other scenarios.
I up-voted your comment for the cleverness and because it solves (for now) my problem. I still hope to find someone to explain why my code isn't working. Tank you for finding the time to read through my long formula and for rewriting it.

Comment: @ScottCraner Hello again, I have tried to copy your formula in VBA and I am getting the same error, however, in Excel it works with no issues. Do you have any clue why it shouldn't work for me? Thanks

Comment: with all the `"` it comes out more than 255.  Dang, sorry thought I had it.

Comment: Try this: `=INDEX($K$7:$K$43,IFERROR(IFERROR(MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(C7=$C$7:$C$43),0),MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(IF(C7<>"AFT","AFT","EVE")=$C$7:$C$43),0)),MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(IF(C7<>"MOR","MOR","EVE")=$C$7:$C$43),0)))`

Comment: this works: `ActiveSheet.Range("W7").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($K$7:$K$43,IFERROR(IFERROR(MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(C7=$C$7:$C$43),0),MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(IF(C7<>""AFT"",""AFT"",""EVE"")=$C$7:$C$43),0)),MATCH(1,(E7=$I$7:$I$43)*(IF(C7<>""MOR"",""MOR"",""EVE"")=$C$7:$C$43),0)))"`

Comment: @ ScottCraner, yes, no errors, I don't know how you managed to reduce the formula even more, but it works. I will test it in multiple scenarios, I hope it keeps working or I will have to go back to my previous formula. For now thanks a lot for all your help.